# What is really happening with bash backticks?

Tags: bash, expansion

I've always thought of backticks in bash as "execute the output of `'some_command'`." What is happening in the following... consider a script `myscript.pl` that prints the following text:

```
   export PS1="[STRING] $PS1"
```

If I copy the output from `cat file.txt` to the command line and execute, "[STRING] " gets added to the front of my prompt.

On the other hand, backtick-ing `'myscript.pl'` makes my prompt `"[STRING]`. What is happening?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting - I couldn't get backticks to show up in a code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash` doesn't *execute* the output of a backtick command, only substitutes it. (The feature is called [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) after all.)

If the substitution is not double-quoted, [word splitting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit) is done to the command's output, but quotes and other special characters are ignored; `export PS1="[STRING] $PS1"` is simply split by `$IFS` to:

- `export`
- `PS1="[STRING`
- `$PS1"`

---

If you want to execute a file's contents, source it:

```
. ./file.txt
```

or, non-POSIX:

```
source ./file.txt
```

If you want all standard parsing to be applied to a substitution -- for example, a variable -- you can use [`eval "$commands"` or `eval "$(foo)"` or `` eval "`foo`" ``](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). But be very careful with it.

Comment: Let me clarify my question. I'm not actually storing commands in a text file, but thought that would be a good way to learn about my problem. I've got a Perl script set up to set up a environment variables. To avoid losing the current environment (not actually the right word - aliases, function, shell variables, etc.) I'm having the script dump _changes_ to the environment, that the user will hopefully be able to apply by using backticks to invoke the script.

Comment: However I see putting eval in front of my backticked expression works as I'd like it to

Comment: @ajwood: Let me point out the last paragraph of my answer. (**Do not forget quotes.** Otherwise stuff breaks.)